# LWC put string results from apex call into fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I can't seem to get the individual values from my returned list - how do I do this please? What do I replace the ? for each field? The results returned will always only be these 2 fields. The Apex call returns a list of strings as shown in the alert.

```
.then(result => {
    alert('results: ' + result); // this returns the following:    results: abc,def
    this.field1 = ?;   //I want abc in here
    this.field2 = ??;  //and def in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more playing around it seems it's as simple as

```
this.field1 = results[0];
this.field2 = results[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assign multiple values from an array:

```
.then(result => [this.field1, this.field2] = result);
```